# Machine Learning Predictions and Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, prediction

I am using z-score to normalize my data before training my model. When I do predictions on a daily basis, I tend to have very few observations each day, perhaps just a dozen or so. My question is, can I normalize the test data just by itself, or should I attach it to the entire training set to normalize it?

The reason I am asking is, the normalization is based on mean and std_dev, which obviously might look very different if my dataset consists only of a few observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not a good idea to predict on a test set using a model trained with a very different data distribution. I would use the same mean and std of your training data to normalize you test set.

Comment: So the easiest would be to normalize the prediction data together with the training data and then separate both, right?

Comment: You should only normalize the training data, and apply the transformation, as Prune mentioned, to the test data. The assumption is that the underlying data distribution of your data stays the same. Unless you retrain your model to incorporate the new test data, you should not use them to normalize the training set.

Comment: Ok I have 2 questions here:

The approach depends on whether we are talking about testing vs. acutally predicting, right?

For testing I should not let the training data use any information in testing

For prediction, it could be useful to do exactly that right?

Comment: Also, I am using Python's scipy.stats.mstats.zscore to compute z-scores. Do any of you know of a function that will allow me to compute the z-scores based on previously obtained means and std. I would really like to avoid having to do this by hand.

Comment: @NiccolaTartaglia: normalization does not break the security boundary between training and test data ... in fact, to get valid results, you *must* normalize them with the same transformation.

Comment: Similarly, when you predict, you *must* use that transformation again.  You have to have all of the input data on the same "units", whether the data are train, test, or predict.

Comment: I am not quite following here. Are you saying normalization SHOULD NOT break the security boundary or are you saying it is no problem if it breaks the boundary.

Comment: I know of no function which will do what you want -- because it's a trivial linear transformation:  `z_score = (x - X_mean) / X_std_dev`

Comment: So should I normalize ONLY on training data, and then use the mean and STD and apply this to testing and prediction data?

Comment: Normalization of all input, to the same standards, is *required* to maintain data integrity.

Comment: Yes, the normalization strategy you give is the most philosophically sound.  However, there's nothing wrong with normalizing all of your data together, then splitting the data sets.

Comment: So what you are saying is, take all the data: training+testing+prediction=X, and normalize X. And then split them back into training+testing+prediction.

Comment: I see. So both approaches should be fine. Since normalizing alltogether is easier for me, I will stick to that. So there is a tiny bit of look ahead bias (since my training date is normalized using info from testing, but you are saying that should not be too much of a problem, right?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all of your data in the same units.  Among other things, this means that you need to use the same normalization transformation for all of your input.  You don't need to include the new data in the training *per se* -- however, keep the parameters of the normalization (the `m` and `b` of `y = mx + b`) and apply those to the test data as you receive them.

Comment: So the easiest would be to normalize the prediction data together with the training data and then separate both, right?